# launching application on boot crashes the app

Tags: java, android, boot

I tried some of the solutions I have found online for launching my activity on boot. Currently I have:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name="App_Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Main Activity:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {           

        // Start the service or activity 
        Intent startActivity = new Intent();    
        startActivity.setClassName("org.package_name", "org.package_name.MainActivity");
        startActivity(startActivity);      

    }
}
```

However,  when I boot the phone I get the error that my app was stopped in an unexpected way (i.e. crashes). What am I doing wrong any ideas ? (Testing on Android 2.2, API 8)

Comment: Please share the stacktrace.

Comment: @Faizan I am debugging it no a real device so I am not sure how to do that since when I turn the device off, the debug mode stops

Comment: Need to look the stacktrace for understanding. LogCat eclipse iDE..or you can have an application aLogcat from market. But do provide stacktrace here :)

Answer (score 1):

**Boot completed requires the** `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.`

**Edit** Please write package name with receiver name.

```
<receiver android:name="org.package_name.App_Receiver">

Intent startActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);    
startActivity(startActivity);
```

Comment: I have that sorry for not including it. Edited now

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer posted above: it needs permission, and:

```
startActivity.setClassName("org.package_name", "org.package_name.MainActivity");
```

Make sure you have declared that Activity public in Manifest file, also please provide a stack trace to see the problem exactly.

An example for the activity declaration in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I declare the activity public ?

Comment: just in "normal" way in xml, but need to be declared in manifest, otherwise you are getting error / crash.

Comment: It's already declared. It also has this:             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: it would help a lot the exception message, stack trace, please share it, as others requested too. Put your phone in debug mode, connect with usb cable, start Eclipse, switch to DDMS and copy-paste the logcat